# Symfony2 - Problem with entity relation and doctrine request

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity offer which has a oneToOne relation with a product and I have a user who would like to get all the offers he got on his products.

I would like to access to the user who has made the product from an offer in my SQL request.

So it's something like that:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$listofofferusergot = $em->getRepository('blabla:Offer')->findBy(array('product.autor.id' => $user->getId()));
```

(ps : Offer has a OneToOne relation with product)
(ps2: the thing I wrote doesn't work )

So the question is general Can I simply access to a subfield (like id in my case) or must I do a `$em->createQuery()` stuff

offer class:

```
<?php

namespace Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Offer
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity\OfferRepository")
 */
class Offer
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
     private $product;

     ...
}
```

for the product class:

```php
<?php

    namespace Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Product
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Nemi\TwigBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
     */
    class Product
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nemi\UserBundle\Entity\User")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
         */
        private $autor;

        ....

     }
```

Comment: Can I see your entity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this method in your OfferRepository:

```
public function findOffersByProductAuthor(User $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('offer')
         ->join('offer.product', 'product')
         ->join('product.author', 'author')
         ->where('author = :user')
         ->setParameter('user', $user)
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResults();
}
```

Then, call:

```
$em->getRepository('blabla:Offer')-> findOffersByProductAuthor($this->getUser());
```

Comment: I would name the function "findOffersByProductAuthor" since the offer also has user

Comment: alright thx it's working ! but so there is no way to do the same just using  findBy() ?

Comment: The findBy is just a shortcut, you can filter over properties of the entity you are requesting, but you cannot use joins, that are required in this case.